# Map Cypher query result to DTO

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I want to map cypher query results to a DTO/POJO class. I have the following entities defined in neo4j:

1. Products , which has properties; Name, Title, Address
2. Sellers, which has properties; Name, Id
3. Listings, which has properties; Name, Id

Relationshps are defined as: Products -> Sellers & Sellers -> Listings

My query results is List of  `Product.Name, [ {Listings.Name, Listings.Id, Sellers.Id, Sellers.Name} ]`.
I wish to map this to a DTO, I am not able map this result which has different nodes and labels to a DTO/POJO class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already noticed, Spring Data Neo4j is more strict when it comes to map "arbitrary" data that is not directly applicable to one domain entity.
But on the other hand Spring Data Neo4j also offers support for mapping loose data with the `Neo4jClient`.
Example:

```
class SoldProductInformation {
   String productName;
   Set<SellingInformation> sellingInformation;
}

class SellingInformation {
   String listingsName;
   String listingsId;
   String sellerName;
   String sellerId
}
```

```
neo4jClient.query("...return product.name as productName, someListWithTheInformationFromTheQuestion")
  .fetchAs(SoldProductInformation.class)
  .mappedBy((TypeSystem t, Record record) -> {
         String productName = record.get("productName").asString();
         List<SellingInformation> sellingInformations = record.get("someListWithTheInformationFromTheQuestion").asList(value -> {
             String listingsName = value.get("listingsName").asString();
             // same for listingsId, sellerName, sellerId...
             return new SellingInformation(....);
         });
         return new SoldProductInformation(....);
  })
```

If you have more entity aligned fields and/or maybe return also nodes, you can make use of the derived mapping function:

```
BiFunction<TypeSystem, MapAccessor, Product> mappingFunction = neo4jMappingContext.getRequiredMappingFunctionFor(Product.class);
```

and apply it via

```
neo4jClient.query("...return product,...")
  .fetchAs(SoldProductInformation.class)
  .mappedBy((TypeSystem t, Record record) -> {
      Product product = mappingFunction.apply(typeSystem, record.get("product"));
      String productName = product.getName();
// ....
```

see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/2288#issuecomment-861255508  for a complete example.

Comment: I tried this, thinking I could use it to retrieve a DTO with a subset of fields that I want. Unfortunately it throws an error

Could not find mappable nodes or relationships inside node<10> for org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.mapping.DefaultNeo4jPersistentEntity@6393bf8b

I guess I'll have to switch back to the grind of mapping each individual field using the neo4j Driver classes :(

Comment: If the subset is a subset of fields of a declared entity, this should work. Could you raise a new question with some code?